# Kickme command, cannot read tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

im trying to get a command added to my bot, i cant quite figure out why the property of 'tag' is undefined. ${user.tag} works just fine in my real kick command, it just doesnt want to register the user that send the '!kickme' command's tag Below is my code and error

**CODE**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {


    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    const member = message.guild.member(user);

    message.author.send(`Here is an invite so you can join back! https://discord.gg/FBXSduget2 `)

    message.channel.send(`!kick ${user.tag} `)

    message.channel.send(`${user.tag} Kicked themself`)
}

  module.exports.help = {
    name: "kickme"
  }
```

**ERROR**

```
(node:13204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj\-Tux V2\commands\kickme.js:12:40)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj\-Tux V2\main.js:42:31)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled 
with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)    
(node:13204) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like no one is mentioned in the message — `user` is `undefined`. Since you want to kick the user who sends the message, you can get it via [message.author](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author).

```js
const user = message.author
```

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about that