# kickme discord.js command, kicks before can dm

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im having some issues getting the command to wait for the bot to dm the user before it kicks them, ive put in a wait 5 second function but it kicks well before 5 seconds is up Below is my code and error.

its saying 'wait' isnt defined but ive looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66468056/kickme-command-cannot-read-tag) and used one of those, with a slight modification.

also i have another not so important question, how would i make it so whoever runs the !kickme command gets logged into a .txt file or something similar?

Edit: i figured id clarify. Yes im trying to kick the user who sent the !kickme command. its meant to be a completely useless command for people to mess around with. it should send them a dm with the server invite(so they can rejoin) and then kick them.

as of now it isnt sending the dm to them, its just kicking them

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    const user = message.author
    const member = message.guild.member(user);

    message.author.send(`Here is an invite so you can join back! https://discord.gg/FBXSduget2 `)
    
    const timew = async (bot, message, args) => {
        wait(5000);
        console.log("Waited 5s");
      
        wait(5000);
        console.log("Waited an additional 5s");
      };

      timew();
    
    if (member) {
        member
          .kick('User was kicked')
          .then(() => {
            console.log(`${user.tag} Kicked themself`);
            message.channel.send(`${user.tag} kicked themself`)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            message.reply('Unable');
            console.error(err);
          });
        }
    }

  module.exports.help = {
    name: "kickme"
  }
```

```
(node:13216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: wait is not defined
    at timew (C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj\-Tux V2\commands\kickme.js:12:9)
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj\-Tux V2\commands\kickme.js:19:7)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\8fwbu\Desktop\CodeTProj\-Tux V2\main.js:42:31)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled 
with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)    
(node:13216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:13216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\8fwbu\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
(node:13216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled 
with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)    
Unicorn-Barf#9255 Kicked themself
```

Comment: well, the problem is exactly what it says, `wait` appears to be a function that you never defined anywhere. As to your other problem, you can just use a `.then()` on the message that you send and kick the user in there.

Comment: also, it looks like you try to kick the person who sends the message. Maybe not exactly what you wanted to do.

Comment: Instead of using `message.guild.member(user)` you can use `message.member`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from using `wait(5000);` as this is not defined.

You can use `await` when sending messages to ensure they are sent.

```js
await message.author.send(`Here is an invite`)
message.member.kick('they kicked themself')
```